# Why are only my test adverts working on AdMob?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an app I have trying to place adverts on.  The app is not yet published (not sure if this makes a difference).  When I am trying to add an advert it was working perfectly in test mode.  Once I removed line 3 in my example, I expected to get a proper advert but I get nothing.  Looking at LogCat I can see I have a request for the advert.

```
    mAd = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "<my publisher id>");
    AdRequest ad = new AdRequest();
    ad.addTestDevice("<my phone id>");
    System.out.println(ad.isTestDevice(this));
    mAd.loadAd(ad);

LogCat: 01-08 21:26:57.982: I/Ads(7787): adRequestUrlHtml: .......
```

Is there anything else I need to do to see a real advert? Can I actually see a real advert if my app is unpublished? I am still running the app from eclipse onto my development phone.

Thanks.

Comment: on a side node, you should use `Log.i(TAG, message);` for debugging purposes. sysout does not work in android.

Comment: thanks, I will in the future, I just wanted to quickly check what the result was, it did actually appear in the LogCat tab (as false when line 3 commented)

Comment: Sysout works in android but it isn't recommended at all. Doing it for fast debugging works since ages for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience you just have to wait until the first real ad shows up. When you create a new "website/application" on AdMob, it can take a while.

*Note: The very first time AdMob sees your publisher ID it may take up to two minutes to receive an ad. This initial two minute lag will recur every time the ID goes unused for 24 hours.*

Source: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

scroll to the bottom

Hope it helps :)

Edit:
I would recommend, just open the Activity which contains the ad and let the phone lie on the table until something shows up.

Comment: working after I left it for a while, thanks.  I just didn't realise I needed to.

Answer (score 0):

**For Real/Live Ads**

Taken from: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
// Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
// the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
// Add the adView to it
layout.addView(adView);
// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Also, Take Note:

- It may take some time for them to start coming in. Rarely, but possibly a day, initially.
- Login to your admob.com account and make sure it shows communication is active.

**For Test Mode**

Best Practices for enabling Admob Test Ads:

http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/bestpractices.html#testmode

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);               // Emulator
adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");                      // Test Android Device
```

Comment: my problem is that the test adverts are working in eclipse, but the real ones are not displaying

Comment: Then your problem is, you're still in test mode. I will update my answer.

Comment: If you read my question I removed the add test device line, and added System.out.println(ad.isTestDevice(this)), this returned false so I am not in test mode.

Comment: Then, if you've done everything correctly, I assume you just have to wait.

Comment: Ok I did only sign up for my account 2 hours before.  It says I have received 16 requests but no impressions.  As the app is not published these are me testing.  Maybe I have to wait the day I don't remember seeing that though.

Comment: Yes, especially if you just created your account let alone starting the ad requests.